# Amazon EC2 mail limit reached while using external smtp server to send emails

Tags: linux, email, grails, amazon-ec2, jakarta-mail

Hi
I am sending lots of emails from and Amazon EC2 linux instance using grails MailSender Service(Uses  Java Mail API underneath). I have configured the Mail API to use an external smtp server on port 25 to send the emails and I could verify from the external email server logs that emails are indeed sent by them.

But Amazon AWS has sent me an email saying that I reached their email sending limit to send out of SMTP port 25 .

I am not able to understand how did I reach the limit when I have always used external smtp server to send emails.  Additionally, I do get intermittent connection timeout errors for connecting to the external smtp server from the Java Mail API.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

There's a limit on outbound emails to stop spamming (I presume). You can request to override this:
https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request

Answer (score 5):

By the way, if you're sending large volumes of E-mail from AWS infrastructure, you might be interested in this new service: [Amazon Simple Email Service](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/).

Answer (score 1):

They probably restrict the number of total connections on port 25, and as you used that port to connect to the external server, it would be the same as sending the email directly from the server.

Comment: I need a bit more help on this please. How do you restrict total connections? is the total number of packets sent restricted or total concurrent connections?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion will be until amazon removes your smtp limit, connect to your email server using VPN.
I had a similar issue using phpmailer with tls and sasl authentication on port 25. Because we are hosting our email server I was able to use the VPN to connect on the email server and send emails out.