# How to View SMTP Server Logs on AWS EC2 Linux Apache Instance?

Tags: linux, apache, amazon-ec2, smtp

I have an EC2 instance running the standard LAMP stack (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP).  I am using PHP to send out a few e-mails a day (4 or 5 at the most).  This is working without a hitch.

Every once in a while, I will need to debug or test some of the e-mails that are sent.  To do this, I will run a particular e-mail sending script 10-20 times in succession.  I noticed that some of those e-mails are never received by the listed e-mail addresses.  This is sporadic and happens when the script has not been changed.  I am assuming this is because EC2's built-in SMTP server is throttling my e-mails.

How do I view the logs for the SMTP server on EC2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is using your localhost as SMTP server, your logs should be in `/var/log/maillog`.

Note: There is a limitation from AWS for emails sent from EC2 instances:

[AWS EC2 email sending limit when using third party smtp server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311747/aws-ec2-email-sending-limit-when-using-third-party-smtp-server/26316537#26316537)

[Amazon EC2 mail limit reached while using external smtp server to send emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124128/amazon-ec2-mail-limit-reached-while-using-external-smtp-server-to-send-emails)